# home made chicken bake keeps bursting

Tags: baking, dough

I am making home made Costco chicken bake (cheese and chicken wrapped in bread pocket).  However everytime I bake it the fillings leak out and burst from the bread.  Anyway to stop this do I just need to make the dough thicker?

Comment: Do you put any holes or slits in the dough before baking?

Comment: How is it breaking?   You typically want to cut some vent holes to keep air from pressurizing and bursting things, but pressing all of the air out and baking slowly might be enough.  If it’s bursting at the seams, there might be things you can do like pressing down with the tines of a fork or brushing with water or beaten egg to make sure it seals well.  If you’re willing to sacrifice shape, you can also put them into a muffin tin to make what some people call ‘pie bombs’

Comment: @moscafj negative, and since there is ceaser dressing I would imagine some liguid might leaak out if I did that?

Comment: @Joe The cheese and ceaser dressing leak out from the side and the bread burst

Comment: @Lightsout how are you folding the crust?  There’s empanada style where it’s a circle folded in half, or you can make something rectangular and thin like a pop tart, or thick like a mini Stromboli.  Or like a galette where you put it in the middle of a circle and fold the edges in.  Or probably lots of other ways (I used to go to an empanada place that folded and slit each one differently so they could tell them apart, and they had about 20 types)

Answer (score 3):

You need some way for steam inside to escape.  I would try pricking some holes into the dough...maybe a small slit on top.  Losing a little dressing might be the result, but probably better then it bursting.  If you cook gently, you might not even lose the dressing.